# function won't let me return string

Tags: c#, string

This function below should in theory return a string("join") but when I write "return join;" it gives me an error saying: `use of unassigned local variable "join".` here is my code:

```
public string function(string input)
{
    string join;
    var token = input.Split('.').Select(p => Regex.Split(p, " ")).ToArray();
    for (int i = 0; i <= token.Length; i++)
    {
         join = string.Join(" ", token[i]);
    }
    return join;
}
```

I don't see any reason for that error to be caused!

Comment: `string join = "";`

Comment: `token` is null so `join` never gets assigned any value. I assume your LINQ is incorrect in some way.

Comment: How do you know that the loop body will execute at least one time?

Comment: @L.B thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

join is being assigned only inside the "for", it means what happens if token.Length is 0? Join will never be assigned. You should initialize the variable: string joing = "";
Have a good day!

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring the `string` variable `join` without giving it an initial value.  If the regex were to produce no tokens, for example, the `token` array might be empty, and the `for` loop will be skipped.  The value of the `join` variable will never be set.

Even if you know this condition to be impossible based on the spec of the method, the compiler does not necessarily know that, so it results in the compiler error that the variable needs to be declared.

A simple way around this error is to set the value to null or the empty string:

```
string join = null; // or ""
```